# Little tricky programme output

Tags: c, printf

For the snippet I thought but couldn't find reason.

```
printf("%d",printf("tim"));
```

Why is this printing 3 with the output.the output is `tim3`. Why??

Comment: The output is not tricky. It is rather natural as first the inner printf prints its string and then returns its output, 3, to the outer printf, and thus, 3 follows printed string, here "tim".

Comment: Quite surprising.............

Comment: Why are there downvotes?

Comment: Do scholars keep right to supress learners?

Comment: If u can't help pls.don't downvote atleast

Comment: Personally, I never downvote a post.

Comment: @Khan i too agree this is a good question. but the one who has seen lot of this type question seems the question to be silly.

Answer (score 2):

`printf()` returns the number of characters successfully it printed.So in this case it is 3

Check the man:
http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf

`"tim"` is 3 characters.

The inner `printf()` returned 3 after printing `tim` the outer printf() is using this value and printing out 3.

Comment: one char as a whole is printf...

Comment: @Khan *"one char as a whole is printf"* huh??

Comment: @Khan "tim" is 3 characters !!!

Comment: @Khan "tim" is a word consisting of three characters 't', 'i', and 'm'.

Answer (score 1):

There are two `printf()`s.

1. the inner `printf()` [`printf("tim")`]executes first, prints "tim" and retuns the `number` of successfully printed characters[`3` for `tim`].
2. The return of first `printf()` is input to the second `printf()` [`printf("%d",printf("tim"));`], effectively making it `printf("%d", 3);`. So, its printing 3.

I suggest you checking the retrun value of `printf()` in the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf). It states

> Upon successful return, these functions return the number of
>   characters printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to
>   strings).